# How to use Atlassian Bamboo variables in Maven pom.xml?

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, bamboo

I want to use Atlassian Bamboo to deploy non-Maven artifacts, that is artifacts created outside of Maven in another Bamboo task. So I created a Maven 3.x task and put it after the task that creates the artifacts and put deploy:deploy-file in the Goal box. The goal configuration requires the full path of the file I want to deploy. So I did this...

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>deploy-my_artifact-tgz</id>
          <phase>deploy</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>deploy-file</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <!-- Will this work??? -->                
            <file>${bamboo.build.working.directory}/dist/my_artifact.tgz</file>
            <url>${project.repoUrl}</url>
            <repositoryId>${project.repoId}</repositoryId>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}.rtim.garner</groupId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <artifactId>my_artifact</artifactId>
            <packaging>tgz</packaging>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Can I use the ${bamboo.build.working.directory} to define part of the file path inside the  part of the , as I have above? Should I expect Bamboo to substitute this to the correct value?

NOTE: Showing the effective pom in the Bamboo job does not substitute the varables' corresponding value so I can't tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to pass it the value of the variable. So I have this in my Goal text box of my Bamboo Maven task.

```
-Dbamboo.build.working.directory=${bamboo.build.working.directory} deploy:deploy-file
```